# Deep learning methods with seasonal data

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

I have been building an LSTM model in Python which will predict the number of passengers arriving at a station in the next 15 mins.

My dataset is arrivals at the station every 15 mins across a 50 day period. A plot of the data shows a clear seasonal pattern i.e. most entries to the station occur during the evening rush hour.

My question is this: prior to training an LSTM model, do I need to clean up the data - by this I mean take differences to make it stationary? I have normalised the data as all the examples I have seen say it's best to do this, but I am unclear about whether the trend/seasonality should be removed.

Comment: With something as powerful as LSTM, you should theoretically not need to apply transformations for wide sense stationarity (recurrent connections should make up for that). I assume the frequency is 15m so the series will be multi-seasonal. What is the length of the series and do you have exogenous regressors?

Comment: in my experience it helps a lot to make the data stationary

Comment: Why don't you post your data and I will pursue an analysis.using traditional time series methods.

Comment: I have been involved with taco-bell to make and deliver usefil models that will forecast at the 15 minute interval level and provide early warning when things don't go as they are expected to.

Comment: A stationary time series is one whose properties do not depend on the time at which the series is observed. In other words, your data will not have temporal dependencies, which renders LSTM to be meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

I‘m not familiar with LSTM, but I suggest keeping the trend in the data. Otherwise, the model will not be able to learn this trend.

Also, if LSTM can manage it, you should add the time of the day as one of your features.

Answer (score -1):

No, you do not need to make it stationary - there is no such theorem. You can try it, and maybe it will give you better results, since stationary series is easier to forecast, but it is no rule.

As a rule, if there is a trend, then the series should be differenced (LSTM often fits trends badly, though it is no rule), but seasonality is easily predicted using LSTM given sufficient steps back in time (if you split it into subsequences, which you have to do almost always due to performance issues, these subsequences have to be of sufficient length to cover any seasonality you want to account for). So, difference if there is a trend, leave it be if there is a seasonal pattern.

Stationarity is important only in relation to ARIMA-type models. LSTM in theory can discover non-linear relationships, and has no assumption about error distribution, and, thus, can go around non-stationarity.

Comment: LSTM will not recognize seasonality magically in a typical setup that people try to use it in, e.g. to forecast next 15 minutes they feed last few days or hours. If you have annual seasonality, I bet LSTM will not notice it in many cases. You better feed the seasonalily features directly

Comment: It will, you will just need windows of length equal to around 2 years. Also the architecture plays an important role - to recognize long-term seasonalities, it is critical to use stacked LSTM (2 is enough - with 1-layer LSTM the sequence has to be even longer, with more neurons). Ofc, 2 years for 15-minute data will never complete training, but we're talking theory here. I personally model long seasonalities using Fourier components.

Comment: I qualified "typical" for a reason. I haven't seen forecasting for next 15 minutes that requires you to input two years worth of data. It may happen, but it's not a typical situation. You can train a model on years of data, but your sample will be a few days or hours inputs, and that's what is an input. In this setup LSTM is likely to overlook the annual seasonality, the depth of field, so to speak, is too narrow.

Comment: But using 1-year seasonality for 15-minute forecast is already not typical. Modelling 15 minutes with yearly seasonality is purely theoretical question (since yearly part of seasonality will be like.. 0.000001 part of passenger?).

Comment: It's not atypical. Suppose, you're forecasting the retail web site traffic. It obviously has annual seasonality anchored by multiple holidays. So, you create a feature (input) that signals such holidays or otherwise season of the year in addition to a few hours or days of recent traffic. This way you don't need to have a very long memory in LSTM, a few hours or days is enough aided with seasonal signal to capture annual seasonality

Comment: You are describing a standard way to fix calendar effects, these are a different thing from seasonality. Yes, you do not need to have a very long LSTM to do that. I am arguing here, that it is possible to model very long seasonalities with LSTM, but not typical. But to forecast the next 15 minutes, yearly seasonality is not necessary as such, because it can be learned from the most recent observations as trend, and i think that it is gonna be completely insignificant in OP's case, that's why I called his case not typical (using yearly seasonality to forecast next 15 minutes of passenger data)